# Python lxml XPath problem

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to print/save a certain element's HTML from a web-page.
I've retrieved the requested element's XPath from firebug.

All I wish is to save this element to a file.
I don't seem to succeed in doing so.
(tried the XPath with and without a `/text()` at the end)

I would appreciate any help, or past experience.
10x, David

```
import urllib2,StringIO
from lxml import etree

url='http://www.tutiempo.net/en/Climate/Londres_Heathrow_Airport/12-2009/37720.htm'
seite = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = seite.read()
seite.close()
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)
xpath = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/text()"
elem = tree.xpath(xpath)


print elem[0].strip().encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This is a **FAQ: Browsers add mandatory (X)HTML elements to the DOM** (i.e. `head` and `tbody`). Don't trust Firebug. Take a look into the source document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with lxml xpath for html table extracting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586296/problem-with-lxml-xpath-for-html-table-extracting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your XPath is obviously a bit too long, why don't you try shorter ones and see if they match. One problem might be "tbody" which gets automatically created in the DOM by browsers but the HTML markup usually does not contain it.

Here's an example of how to use XPath results:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> doc = etree.parse(StringIO("<html><body>a<something/>b</body></root>"), etree.HTMLParser())
>>> doc.xpath("/html/body/text()")
['a', 'b']
```

So you could just `"".join(...)` all text parts together if needed.

Comment: @It's not that it's too long. However, your tbody remark was absoloutley correct. Wouldnt've thought about that in a million years. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely follow what you are trying to accomplish, but ultimately I think you are looking for:

```
print etree.tostring(elem[0])
```