# Extracting lxml xpath for html table

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-table, lxml

I have a html doc similar to following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div id="Symbols" class="cb">
    <table class="quotes">
    <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">High</th>
        <th style="text-align:right;">Low</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ro" onclick="location.href='/xyz.com/A.htm';" style="color:red;">
        <td><a href="/xyz.com/A.htm" title="Display,A">A</a></td>
        <td>A Inc.</td>
        <td align="right">45.44</td>
        <td align="right">44.26</td>
    <tr class="re" onclick="location.href='/xyz.com/B.htm';" style="color:red;">
        <td><a href="/xyz.com/B.htm" title="Display,B">B</a></td>
        <td>B Inc.</td>
        <td align="right">18.29</td>
        <td align="right">17.92</td>
</div></html>
```

I need to extract `code/name/high/low` information from the table.

I used following code from one of the similar examples in Stack Over Flow:

```
#############################
import urllib2
from lxml import html, etree

webpg = urllib2.urlopen(http://www.eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/A.htm).read()
table = html.fromstring(webpg)

for row in table.xpath('//table[@class="quotes"]/tbody/tr'):
    for column in row.xpath('./th[position()>0]/text() | ./td[position()=1]/a/text() | ./td[position()>1]/text()'):
        print column.strip(),
    print

#############################
```

I am getting nothing output. I have to change the first loop xpath to `table.xpath('//tr')` from `table.xpath('//table[@class="quotes"]/tbody/tr')`

I just don't understand why the `xpath('//table[@class="quotes"]/tbody/tr')` not work.

Comment: i found my problem. Somehow the <tbody> tag got removed. From Firebug the <tbody> does show up right after <table class="quotes"> and before <tr> tag.

Comment: Yes this is a **FAQ: browsers add mandatory (X)HTML elements (like `head` and `tbody`) to DOM.** By the way this is exactly what @samplebias' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586296/problem-with-lxml-xpath-for-html-table-extracting/5586627#5586627) say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python lxml XPath problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333236/python-lxml-xpath-problem)

Answer (score 43):

You are probably looking at the HTML in Firebug, correct?  The browser will insert the implicit tag `<tbody>` when it is not present in the document.  The lxml library will only process the tags present in the raw HTML string.

Omit the **tbody** level in your XPath. For example, this works:

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(raw_html)
tree.xpath('//table[@class="quotes"]/tr')
[<Element tr at 1014206d0>, <Element tr at 101420738>, <Element tr at 1014207a0>]
```

Comment: I experienced this with Chrome as well.  Was using its `Copy XPath` feature in the 'Inspect' right click menu.  Kinda goofy.

Comment: Do you know of any other "path-changing rules" that can happen in FF/Chrome? It would be interesting to compile them.