# Not able to parse html using lxml Xpath parser

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse review from this page: http://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B00143ZBHY

Using following approach:

**Code**

```
html # a variable which contains exact html as given at the above page.
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(html)
r = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[9]/text()[4]")
print len(r)
print r[0].tag
```

**Output**

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 37, in <module>
    print r[0].tag
IndexError: list index out of range
```

p,s,: While using the same xpath on xpath checker addon of firefox I am able todo it easily.  But no result here, please help!

Comment: dont know why chrome showed tbody in xpath :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to remove `/tbody` form XPath — there is no `<tbody>` in `#productReviews`.

```
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B00143ZBHY").read()
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(html)
r = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='productReviews']/tr/td[1]/div[9]/text()[4]")
print r[0]
```

Output:

```
bought this as replacement for the original cover which came with my greenhouse and which ripped in the wind.  so far this seems a good replacement although for some reason it seems slightly too small for my greenhouse so that i cant zip both sides of the front at the same time.  seems sturdier and thicker than the cover i had before so hoping it lasts a bit longer!
```

Comment: I can accept the answer only after 15 mins from posting the question, wait I would do that in 3 mins

Comment: @dragosrsupercool It's not a silly mistake, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5586627/1167879