# Unable to fetch element using scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have wrote a spider to scrap a few elements from a website but the problem is i am unable to fetch some of the elements and some are working fine. Please help me in right direction.

Here is my spider code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from ScrapyScraper.items import ScrapyscraperItem

class ScrapyscraperSpider(CrawlSpider) :
    name = "rs"
    allowed_domains = ["mega.pk"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mega.pk/mobiles/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ("http://www\.mega\.pk/mobiles_products/[0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z-0-9.]+",)), callback = 'parse_item', follow = True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response) :
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = ScrapyscraperItem()

        item['Heading'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/span/text()').extract()
        item['Content'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/p/text()').extract()
        item['Price'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/text()').extract()
        item['WiFi'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]/tbody/tr/td[contains(. ,"Wireless")]/text()').extract()

        return item
```

Now i am able to get Heading, Content and Price but Wifi returns nothing. The point where i get totally confused is that the same xpath works in chrome and not in python(scrapy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'm still learning myself, though I think I may see your problem.

I would imagine you are looking to find the wifi status - in which case you need the text of the span of the next element:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as LH 

url = 'http://www.mega.pk/laptop_products/13242/Apple-MacBook-Pro-with-Retina-Display-Z0RG0000V.html'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
doc=LH.fromstring(html)
heading = doc.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/span/text()')
content = doc.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/p/text()')
price = doc.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/text()')
wifi_location = doc.xpath('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Wireless")]')[0]
wifi_status = wifi_location.getnext().find('span').text
```

I only checked a single page, but hopefully this helps.  I am unsure why the xpath does not work.. I will be doing more reading but I often find that the inclusion of tbody does not function properly in this setting. I typically have opted to skip to td via //.

**Edit**

Found the reason, it looks like chrome will insert tbody when it is not included in original html.  Scrapy is trying to parse the original HTML without this feature.

[Extracting lxml xpath for html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586296/problem-with-lxml-xpath-for-html-table-extracting)