# lxml: parsing html, unable to get nodes

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get started parsing html with lxml. I know from basic xpath that `/` should select the root node, `//body` should select the body element node wherever it is in the dom, etc. However I am getting an empty list for all of them.

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2
headers =  {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'}
req = urllib2.Request("http://news.ycombinator.com", None, headers)
r = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
x = html.fromstring(r)
x.xpath("/")
[]
```

EDIT:

For example, here is another valid xpath expression for that page which returns an empty list

```
x.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")
[] 
# when it should have returned the following (as of this time)
# <td class="title"><a href="http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/opengl-in-2014/">OpenGL in 2014</a><span class="comhead"> (tomdalling.com) </span></td>
```

Comment: Don't you get this **urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**

Comment: And what does **[]** do?

Comment: @Nabin Oh, in the actual code I am using a proxy and a fake user agent, which I didn't post. The `[]` is the output of the second last line. I will make this code workable, just a min.

Comment: @Nabin I've changed the code, `r` contains the html of the homepage now. Tested it on my machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question: The problem with the xpath expression possibly is the tbody-element.
As you can already find multiple questions with a similar problem on Stackoverflow - e.g. here [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements) and here [Why does firebug add <tbody> to <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678494/why-does-firebug-add-tbody-to-table), the short version
is that browsers add elements like e.g. head and tbody to the DOM that are *not* in the sourcecode,
so the xpath won't match. You can just omit the tbody:

```
x.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr[1]/td[3]")
```

which seems to work as stated here: [Extracting lxml xpath for html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586296/problem-with-lxml-xpath-for-html-table-extracting)

But I favor the approach given in the first answer here [Python lxml XPath problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333236/python-lxml-xpath-problem), 
 - it should also work if you just omit unnecessary parts of the xpath and shorten the query to the element you're looking for, so instead of

```
x.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")
```

you should get the result with

```
x.xpath("/html/tr[3]/tr[1]/td[3]")
```